# Replace for with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

In this script I have used both list comprehension and for. I need to replace for loop with comprehension and add this solve inside list comprehension.

How can add

```
for i in k:
    count_list.append(l.count(i))
```

inside this block

```
pairs = [int(pair/2) for pair in count_list if int(pair/2) != 0]
```

My code:

```
def sockMerchant(ar):
    l = ar
    k = set(l)
    count_list = []
    for i in k:
         count_list.append(l.count(i))
    pairs = [int(pair/2) for pair in count_list if int(pair/2) != 0]
    return sum(pairs)

n = int(input().strip())
ar = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
result = sockMerchant(ar)
print(result)
```

Comment: Can you give example of an argument? Will make it easier

Comment: Why do you want a list comprehension for that? Use a `collections.Counter()` instead, using `list.count()` in a loop is really inefficient.

Comment: Dear Matjin I don't know this module maybe fro this reason :)
I have some solves but I need solve this problem use only list comprehension.

Comment: @BahruzAghalarov: that's a very artificial limitation. If this is homework that requires you to use a list comprehension for the counting code, then I suggest you re-read the class notes and text book, and if need be, ask your tutor for help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What does it mean you cann't solve this task or I misunderstand you ? :)

Comment: @BahruzAghalarov: if you are smart enough to try and manipulate people into answering you, I'm sure you can figure out the list comprehension too. Good luck!

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are not only smart in Python :D
To answer questions you are you are good too :) .Good luck you friend !

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using a list comprehension at all, nor the `for` loop you have now. The loop is inefficient; by using `list.count()` you are traversing the whole list `l` for every unique value, creating a O(N^2) loop.

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead and count in O(N) time:

```
from collections import Counter

def sockMerchant(ar):
    counts = Counter(ar)
    return sum(count//2 for count in counts.values())
```

or even

```
def sockMerchant(ar):
    return sum(count//2 for count in Counter(ar).values())
```

if you insist on a single line.

Note that `sum()` doesn't mind a few `0` values here and there, so I removed the `if` test for single 'socks'. Also, I used the [`//` floor division operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) rather than turning the floating point result of dividing by 2 back into an integer.

Comment: It is ideally solve.thank you for this I will rememeber this metod :)
But my question stayed unanswered :(
How can use this block as list comprehension ? I dont see any solve for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to give you a hammer just to bang on your foot. A list comprehension is a simple tool to build a list, and any `for ...: list.append(...)` loop is trivially converted.

Comment: It is ok that I must use this metod inside another.But my question is stayed open.It is nor problem use list comprehension but I need use just one list comprehensionnot additionllay for loop. If it is possible write about ths please :)